# C#: Make a global static method

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

So, I've been developing a game in Monogame for quite a while, and I'm trying to optimize the code. One of the things that I was trying to optimize was the LoadContent method, which is only present on one of the classes (The Game one) and is used to load assets into the game.

And I thought: Wouldn't it be nice to have a global, static method in every class to load the content themselves, rather than having the Game class to load it for them?

Example:

How I load the content right now:

```
class.LoadContent(c) // c is ContentManager, a variable used for loading assets
class2.LoadContent(c) // LoadContent(c) is a static method
class3.LoadContent(c)
...
```

How I would like to:

```
allTheClassesThatNeedContent.LoadContent(c) // LoadContent(c) is still a static method
// Assets loaded in each and every class!
```

How can I do it like this? Or, is it even possible to do it like I want?

Comment: i don't quiet follow your qs, can u be a bit more clear ? :(

Comment: Sure, there :) @zackraiyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have declared the ContentManager  as *public static* in my main class (Game1 in a default project)

```
public static ContentManager content;
```

With this I can load any content in any class by

```
Game1.content.Load<T>()
```

Especially on bigger projects I do not suggest to load all the data in Game1' *LoadContent()* because you will probably load a lot of content which is not needed on startup (e.g. level data from not visited levels) and this will slow down the game launch significantly when the game gets bigger.

Rather load the content if really needed like in the constructor.

Comment: Nice! I'll just do a static bool now in each class that needs loading assets, and when the class is instantiated, it will load its assets and set the bool to true, so it doesn't load it again when instantiated another time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make an abstract base class from which all of your loadable classes derive.

Then, in the base class constructor, add your class to a static collection (such as `List<T>`). In your static method, call the `LoadContent` method on each of the classes in the collection.

The only problem with this is the classes will need to be removed from the collection before they are disposed. It might be best to stick to your current implementation.

Comment: Yeah, the dispose problem might be a big one, since the game is constantly updating, removing and adding new objects, so I don't think a list would be the solution. And, I'll see if more people try to answer to the question and find a solution, because my current implementation is driving me nuts. Thanks anyways.